# server to server communication set up

Tags: php, android, curl, paypal

I need to communicate with PayPal server to verify payment details submitted via my app. This communication must be done via a cURL script, which i plan to place inside a PHP script.I would like to start the cURL script as soon as the payment id field on my database is filled via my app. My question is how to tell my database server to start this communication with the PayPal server.

Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look into [Instant Payment notification](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

`Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, including automatically fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status`

Answer (score 0):

IPN are inbound HTTP requests. Your sever will receive a call from PayPal when there is information to be processed.
Use http://ipnrelay.com/ to collect your IPN messages while in dev mode.